# How to proxy a docker container port+http to a sub URL?

Tags: http, ubuntu, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy

So I have an array of containers running difrent http servers on 808x. Local URLs are important for them. I want to have a proxy susch that

- if a container `X` expects: `localhost:808X/bla/ble/blu`
- a site user could call it like `site.io/Id_X/bla/ble/blu`
- and proxy would translate URL to `localhost:808X/bla/ble/blu` for the container.

How to do such thing on Ubuntu using Docker?

Comment: Is your server running under apache?

Comment: Sadly no - it is a pvw-presenter server.

Comment: Why not run a normal reverse proxy? Map each container to a different sub-domain. `node1.site.io`, `node2.site.io` .. etc. You can test that out in no time using for example the `jwilder/nginx` image. If you don't have dns records just hack them into your hosts file. This also means you only have to map the revers proxy port to the host and nothing else.

Comment: @Grimmy: this will not work when site.io is simply an IP address:(

Comment: But probably will end up doing something like this https://serverfault.com/a/586614/252361

Comment: You can always hack in some names in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

For the port you just have to pass `-p 80:80` as argument when creating a docker container. Example:

```
$ docker run -d -it -p 80:80 image /bin/bash
```

For the domain name you can try adding a new line in your docker container's `/etc/hosts`. That's easily achievable by doing:

```
$ docker exec -it container_name bash -c "echo '127.0.0.1 site.io' >> /etc/hosts"
```

Comment: Prabably my question was not clear: I updated it. The point was to be able to host an array of containers bound to different sub urls.